# Shorthand or Dispatch switch-statement with function?

Tags: php, if-statement, optimization, switch-statement, shorthand

There is any way to *shorthand* or *dispatch* this to one-line code?

```
$asd='http://asd.asd';
// $asd='asd@asd.asd';
// $asd='+123123';

switch ($asd){
    case strpos($asd, 'http')===0:
        $qwe='href';
        break;
    case strpos($asd, '@')>1:
        $qwe='mailto';
        break;
    case strpos($asd, '+')===0:
        $qwe='tel';
        $break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

   $asd = 'http://asd.asd';
   // $asd = 'asd@asd.asd';
   // $asd = '+123123';

   $qwe = (strpos($asd, 'http') === 0 ? 'href' : (strpos($asd, '@') > 1 ? 'mailto' : (strpos($asd, '+') === 0 ? 'tel' : '')));

   echo $qwe;
?>
```

It's not easy to read but you wanted it to be a single line of code. It's called ternary operator and you read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: the result: https://ideone.com/W35QFP
this is for #wordpress triggered by `theme_mod`s:
`<?php echo properContact(wp_kses_post( get_theme_mod( 'feedback_name_1' )),wp_kses_post( get_theme_mod( 'feedback_url_1' ))); ?>`